# Maximum length of Access validation rule?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a validation rule in access.
I would like to limit the entered character combinations only to the existing ISO 2 digit country codes:

"AF" or "AX" or "AL" or "DZ" or "AS" or "AD" or "AO" or "AI" or "AQ" or "AG" or "AR" or "AM" or "AW" or "AU" or "AT" or "AZ" or "BS" or "BH" or "BD" or "BB" or "BY" or "BE" or "BZ" or "BJ" or "BM" or "BT" or "BO" or "BQ"

It works fine, until I reach character number 798, than over it, it fails with an error message:

> Error in the validation rule: Error in CHECK...(something, I am using a non english office (2007) so I cannot really translate it.)

Any idea? I thought it is because of the length, but it should accommodate 2000 something characters. I could not find anything about the maximum number of expression in a validation rule.

I would appreciate any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a table of acceptable codes, set up a relationship and enforce referential integrity. This type of statement is not what validation is for. You can then use the table in comboboxes in forms to allow the user to easily select the codes.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-HA010072597.aspx

This is tested as a validation rule in Access 2010, but it is horrible!

> IN("AX","AF","AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AQ","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU","AT","AZ","BS","BH","BD","BB","BY","BE","BZ","BJ","BM","BT","BO","BA","BW","BV","BR","IO","BN","BG","BF","BI","KH","CM","CA","CV","KY","CF","TD","CL","CN","CX","CC","CO","KM","CD","CG","CK","CR","CI","HR","CU","CY","CZ","DK","DJ","DM","DO","EC","EG","SV","GQ","ER","EE","ET","FK","FO","FJ","FI","FR","GF","PF","TF","GA","GM","GE","DE","GH","GI","GR","GL","GD","GP","GU","GT","GN","GW","GY","HT","HM","HN","HK","HU","IS","IN","ID","IR","IQ","IE","IL","IT","JM","JP","JO","KZ","KE","KI","KP","KR","KW","KG","LA","LV","LB","LS","LR","LY","LI","LT","LU","MO","MK","MG","MW","MY","MV","ML","MT","MH","MQ","MR","MU","YT","MX","FM","MD","MC","MN","MS","MA","MZ","MM","NA","NR","NP","NL","AN","NC","NZ","NI","NE","NG","NU","NF","MP","NO","OM","PK","PW","PS","PA","PG","PY","PE","PH","PN","PL","PT","PR","QA","RE","RO","RU","RW","SH","KN","LC","PM","VC","WS","SM","ST","SA","SN","CS","SC","SL","SG","SK","SI","SB","SO","ZA","GS","ES","LK","SD","SR","SJ","SZ","SE","CH","SY","TW","TJ","TZ","TH","TL","TG","TK","TO","TT","TN","TR","TM","TC","TV","UG","UA","AE","GB","US","UM","UY","UZ","VU","VA","VE","VN","VG","VI","WF","EH","YE","ZM","ZW")

Comment: Thanks Remou, that is what I wanted to avoid, because I will have tons of such statements and I would avoid the use of several extra tables and relationships. Anyway, if this is the only solution I will do it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel that a difficult-to-control validation rule is better than a table? A table, even lots of tables, is the standard solution for controlling input in a relational database.

Comment: Many codes, what I use are not subject to change. ISO country codes are not the perfect examples, but many others are standards. Most of them has only 4-10 valid values, which can be easily handled in this way, but adding tables and relationships for all of these (couple of hundreds) would result a huge and difficult to understand "network"(on my point of view). Also tables with few data. Maybe I will try to set up a table with all the valid values and figure out the validation on a different way, based on masks and so on. Thanks

Comment: If you really must do this thing, use IN : In ("AA","BA","CA","DA","EA","FA","GA","HA","IA","JA","KA",

Comment: It is one thing to have a validation rule for 3 or 4 values, but a validation rule for over 100 is not, IMHO, a good idea.

Comment: I have tried the "In" also, It did not like it at all...I think the silly local settings are my worste enemies...You are right, it is not the best idea, and it does not work so i will find an other solution probably your advice is the one i will use.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, Im not trying to argue with You, I know this option, I was just curious whether there is anything else I could use. I would like to use the smartest solution, and I was wondering whether is there anything I forgot or do not know.

Comment: Absolutely, new ideas are great.